# how i can print the elements in this single linked list in reverse order using c++

Tags: c++

```
            #include <iostream>
            #include<string>
            using namespace std;

            struct nodeType
            {
                int info;
                nodeType *next;
            };

            class linkedListType
            {
            private:
                nodeType *first, *last;
                int length;

            public:
                linkedListType()//constructor
                {
                    first = last = NULL;
                    length = 0;
                }

                void print() // normal print
                {
                    nodeType * current = first;
                    while (current != NULL)
                    {
                        cout << current->info <<" ";
                        // update statement
                        current = current ->next;
                    }
                }


                void insertEnd(int item) //insert item to the end of the list
                {  // forward insertion 
                    nodeType* newNode = new nodeType;
                    newNode ->info = item;

                    if (length == 0)
                    {
                        first = last = newNode;
                        newNode->next = NULL;
                    }//if

                    else
                    {
                        last->next = newNode;
                        last =  newNode;
                        newNode->next = NULL;
                    }// else

                    length++;
                }
                }
                void clearList()
        {
            nodeType * current;
            while ( first != NULL)
            {
                current = first;
                first = first->next;
                delete current;
                length--;
            }// while
    ~linkedListType() //destroctor
        {
            clearList();
        }


> `

//
```

> Blockquote i cant write this method emplement please anyone help me and explane why ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
>               /*this method. can anyone help ma to write it to me and explan why*/
>               ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
`



                void printReverse() /*this is the function that i cant understand it or complete it. this function print elements in the list in reverse*/

                {
                    nodeYype* current=last ,*newnode =new nodType ;
                    for(int i=length;i>=0;i--)
                            //i cant complete this method

                }
            };
            void main()
            {
               linkedListType list1;

               list1.insertEnd(12); //insert item
               list1.insertEnd(25);//insert item
               list1.insertEnd(18);//insert item
               list1.insertEnd(37);//insert item
               list1.insertEnd(60);//insert item
               list1.insertEnd(100);//insert item
               list1.insertEnd(37);//insert item
               list1.insertEnd(37);//insert item
               list1.insertEnd(37);//insert item
               list1.insertEnd(60);//insert item
               list1.insertEnd(25);//insert item
               list1.insertEnd(100);//insert item
               list1.insertEnd(25);//insert item

               cout <<"Printing the linked list elements\n";
               list1.print();
               cout <<"\nPrinting the list elements in reverse order\n";
               list1.printReverse();
            }
```

Comment: Either build a reversed list and iterate through that; or use recursion to build the reversed list on the call stack (and hope the stack is large enough).

Comment: use a std::stack, add all the elements and print them from there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void nodeType::PrintListReverse()
{
  if (next)
     next->PrintListReverse();
  std::cout << info << std::endl;
}
```

Recursively find the end of the list, printing on return.

(I'm only enabling you because I'm bored)

Alternatively:

```
void linkedListType::PrintList()
{
    std::vector<int> info(length);
    nodeType* curNode = first;
    for (int i = 0; curNode != NULL; i++, curNode = curNode->next)
    {
        info[i] = curNode->info;
    }
    for (int i = length-1; i >=0; i--)
    {
        std::cout << info[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont want to use recursive function please write the implementation without recursive function

Answer (score 0):

If you can write a recursive function to traverse the list in proper order, printing it in reverse order is a snap.

Comment: A snap, until the stack overflows.

Comment: That would take a pretty big list.

Comment: @MikeSeymour totally true, but hey, this is most likely a homework assignment.

Comment: Indeed it would; but in my experience computers are often used to deal with pretty big lists.

Comment: i dont want to use recursive function 
please write the implementation without recursive function

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities. Either to write a recursive function or rebuild your list in the reverse order. That is before printing the list you either create a new list on the base pf existent or rebuild the original list itself.

Comment: how i can reach to the backward node and print it each time, what is the code ????

Answer (score 0):

You already have a loop that decrements i  from length to 0.  Based on i, you can traverse the list and print the node that you reached.  Fine tune for off by 1 errors so that you actually print from last to first and don't print when the list is empty.

Comment: Thereby solving an O(n) problem with an O(n^2) solution.

Comment: @ScottHunter: yep, seeing the code and the already loop and the fact that this is an exercise, this seems acceptable.  Also note that in terms of memory, this is even the best solution...

Comment: @ScottHunter: anyway, I guess the OP was only looking for the codez.